wifi driver related issue
image of problem
from the above image you can clearly see the problem it says you are using an alternative driver
note: i also switched that toggle of wifi but nothing happen and issue is still same
i wanted to fix this issue so that my wifi work fine again
settings wifi page
note: all hardware requirement is satisfied to use wifi also i used it last week but don't know where the ussue is and wanted to fix as soon as possible.
i tried to find same problem but not found the solution that seems fit for it (doesn't work at all)
system info dell latitude laptop
wanted to fix this issue till now got this error in kernal logs
[ 1573.649585] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : 
[ 1573.649596] wlp2s0 Scan_results error (-22)


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].
